# Which C++ build configuration should I pick and what makes them all different?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I'm programming with C++ and I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start and debug my code, I get this list:

[image: Screenshot of all of the compilers]

There are so many options and I honestly don't know if they're all different or the same. I usually just pick the first thing that I see. But I want to know what all of these options do.

Comment: `cpp` (preprocessor) and `clang` (without `++` - a C compiler) are wrong tools. You're choosing from `clang++` (possibly suffixed with version) and `g++` (possibly suffixed with version). Run `g++ --version` and `clang++ --version` to see what versions the unsuffixed variants have, and choose the newest `g++` or `clang++`.

Comment: There is likely only one set of executables, but your system has /bin linked to /usr/bin. VSCode is searching both paths because they were historically independent, however in this case they will appear to have the same contents.